# Javascript textarea value only appears after focus?

Tags: forms, textarea

I am having some difficulty with a form field where it is only the textarea field causing the issue that the value appears after I click into the textarea and not already appearing like the input fields:

```
<textarea name="enquiry" id="enquiry" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enquiry') this.value='';" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Enquiry':this.value;" value="Enquiry"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<textarea name="enquiry" id="enquiry" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enquiry') this.value='';" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Enquiry':this.value;">Enquiry</textarea>
```

Just remove the value attribute and put the text inside `<textarea></textarea>`

Comment: Thank you Sir - just waiting for it to let me accept the answer :)